# LVM snapshot stuck during merge

Tags: linux, lvm

I created a snapshot of an LV and I now wish to revert it back to its original state.

Unfortunately, this operation seems to have gone totally wrong and it is now stuck:

```
# /sbin/lvconvert -v --merge /dev/vg01/ubuntu1804-tester-snapshot
    Using logical volume(s) on command line.
  Snapshot ubuntu1804-tester-snapshot is already merging.
  Unable to merge LV "ubuntu1804-tester-snapshot" into its origin.

# lvs --all
  LV                                      VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin                 Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root                                    rhel -wi-------  17,00g                                                                    
  swap                                    rhel -wi-------   2,00g                                                                    
<snip other disks>
  ubuntu1804-tester                       vg01 Owi-a-s---  10,00g                                                                    
  [ubuntu1804-tester-snapshot]            vg01 Swi-a-s---  10,00g      ubuntu1804-tester      100,00
```

Data% remains at 100% no matter what. How can I fix this? Rebooting the entire system is... possible, but should be a last resort.

Comment: Does `dmesg` or the syslog say anything?

Comment: Sorry for the late response (weekend), but no, nothing that I can spot.

Comment: What if you create a new LV, make a snapshot, change the original LV, and merge the snapshot back? In other words, can you reproduce it. Otherwise, the only thing I would say is that merges are delayed when the volumes are open, but they're not, so I'm at a loss at this point.